# IWeakEventListener.ReceiveWeakEvent() called multiple times when PropertyChanged(null) is called on source object

Tags: wpf, mvvm-light, reactive-programming, weakeventmanager

I'm using the [PropertyObserver](https://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2009/07/11/one-way-to-avoid-messy-propertychanged-event-handling/) class in my code to avoid doing string comparisons in `PropertyChanged` event handling and factor out the handling of  `null` or `string.Empty` as its argument (Which [indicates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged.aspx) that all properties of an object has changed).

This class uses `PropertyChangedEventManager` to register callbacks in the target object and implements `IWeakEventListener` to respond every time `PropertyChanged` event is invoked on the source object.

But during the creation of a unit test I found out that the `IWeakEventListener.ReceiveWeakEvent()` is called N number of times, with N as the number of the registered callbacks. This only occurs when null or string.Empty is specified, not when a valid property name is given in the PropertyChanged event.

Does anyone knows why this is happening and how to fix it? My goal is to do a foreach of the registered handlers ONE time when null is given, so I can update my target object by getting all the properties of the source object. But when `ReceiveWeakEvent()` is called N times then the foreach will be repeated N times!

To illustrate it, the following is a simplified version of the PropertyObserver class and the source class (I'm using MVVM Light's `ObservableObject` for `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation):

```
public class PropertyObserver : IWeakEventListener {
    public bool ReceiveWeakEvent(Type managerType, object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (managerType == typeof(PropertyChangedEventManager)) {
            string propertyName = ((PropertyChangedEventArgs)e).PropertyName;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName)) {
                Console.WriteLine ("Foreach registered handlers and invoke one by one");
            } else {
                Console.WriteLine ("Invoke handler for property {0}", propertyName);
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

public class ViewModel : ObservableObject {
    private int mProp1;
    private int mProp2;

    public int Prop1 {
        get { return mProp1; }
        set {
            mProp1 = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Prop1");
        }
    }

    public int Prop2 {
        get { return mProp2; }
        set {
            mProp2 = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Prop2");
        }
    }

    public void RaiseAllPropertyChanged() {
        RaisePropertyChanged(null);
    }
}
```

And in a console app's Main we can call them like so:

```
var vm = new ViewModel();
var obs = new PropertyObserver();

// Normally this is done inside the PropertyObserver class.
PropertyChangedEventManager.AddListener(vm, obs, "Prop1");
PropertyChangedEventManager.AddListener(vm, obs, "Prop2");

vm.Prop1 = 1; // Results in a console line "Invoke handler for property Prop1"
vm.Prop2 = 2; // Results in a console line "Invoke handler for property Prop2"

// Results in two console lines: "Foreach registered handlers and invoke one by one", expected is only 1!
vm.RaiseAllPropertyChanged();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I didn't understand the `AddListener()` method before. I only need to register a listener once:

```
PropertyChangedEventManager.AddListener(vm, obs, string.Empty);
```

to listen to *all* PropertyChanged events of a source object. Doing this will produce the correct working of the PropertyObserver class:

```
vm.Prop1 = 1;    // "Invoke handler for property Prop1"
vm.Prop2 = 2;    // "Invoke handler for property Prop2"

// Now results in one console line "Foreach registered handlers and invoke one by one"
vm.RaisePropertyChanged();
```

Each registered listener with non-empty third argument (the property name) will respond to only the specified property name *and* `null` or `string.Empty`. So that's why the foreach was invoked twice on the original code.